# Question about programmatically changing crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, crystal-reports

General info: C#, VS2008, .NET 3.5

I've got a form with a crystal report viewer inside it, and i'm wanting to use the one form to display all of my crystal reports. I've got it so that i can programmatically change the report, the only problem is that i have to a new method for each crystal report. I'm wanting to create a single method that can take in the database name, server name, and then the CrystalReport. The code shown below is on the form that has the crystal reports viewer.

```
public void setReport(string databaseName, string serverName, ReportType report)
{
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report; 

        CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo crDbConnection = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();
        crDbConnection.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        crDbConnection.DatabaseName = databaseName;
        crDbConnection.ServerName = serverName;
        crDbConnection.UserID = "userid";
        crDbConnection.Password = "password";
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument oRpt = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument)crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource;
        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database crDatabase = oRpt.Database;
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo oCrTableLoginInfo;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table oCrTable in crDatabase.Tables)
        {
            oCrTableLoginInfo = oCrTable.LogOnInfo;
            oCrTableLoginInfo.ConnectionInfo = crDbConnection;
            oCrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(oCrTableLoginInfo);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that i just need to pass the report in as an object, and then set the report source equal to that object.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
 public enum ReportType : int //Must match actual rdlc filename!!
        {
            rptBankPaymentInstructions = 0,
            rptInstructionReconciliation = 1,
            rptMarketValue = 2,
            rptPortfolioInstructionsSummary = 3
        }

private void ShowRpt(ReportType type, string[] parametersValues, string[] parameterNames)
        {
            try
            {
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource =  "ATPresentation.Reports." + type.ToString() + ".rdlc";
                //reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ATPresentation.Reports.rptMarketValue.rdlc";
                ReportEngineService.ReportService rService = new ATPresentation.ReportEngineService.ReportService();


                ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();


                switch (type)
                {
                    case ReportType.rptBankPaymentInstructions:
                        break;
                    case ReportType.rptMarketValue:
                        rds.Name = "Report_MarketValue";

                        ReportEngineService.Report.MarketValueDataTable dt = rService.GetMarketValueDt(Convert.ToInt32(parametersValues[0]), Convert.ToDateTime(parametersValues[1]));
                        rds.Value = dt;
                        //reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Report_MarketValue",dt));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                List<ReportParameter> allParams = new List<ReportParameter>();

                for (int i = 0; i < parametersValues.Length; i++)
                {
                    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter rptParams = new ReportParameter( parameterNames[i], parametersValues[i]);
                    allParams.Add(rptParams);
                }

                reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(allParams);           
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
```

Comment: This would have totally worked if i was trying to use a microsoft report, but my company wants to stick to Crystal Reports. I did however solve my problem. I just needed to feed the report in to my method as an object.